# How to newline in String object using XAML

Tags: xaml

The following code is an example usage of `String` object using XAML with newline attempt:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<system:String x:Key="Add">Add\nNew Item</system:String>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I know it is a little obvious but have you tried breaking the line? I think xaml respects the line breaks and spaces inside the value of tags...

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3974049/525138

Comment: Thank you very much Richard, your link answer worked for me. The key for the answer is `xml:space="preserve"`

Answer (score 0):

```
&#x0a;
```

Use that in your string as described here:

[Newline in string attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183406/xaml-newline-in-string-attribute)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `&#x0d;&#x0a;`

Comment: I now tried but it didn't work as well.